# How to exclude product category from php code in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using this piece of code to display the range price of variable product from € - €€€ to Starting From €. I'm taking the max price and divide it by 10 because my max variation is a pack of 10.

```
add_filter( 'eha_variable_sale_price_html',
'pugliami_variation_price_format_min', 9999, 4 );

function pugliami_variation_price_format_min( $price, $min_price, $maxprices, $regular_price ) {

    $maxprices = sprintf( __( 'Starting from %1$s', 'woocommerce' ),
    wc_price( $maxprices /10) );

    return $maxprices ;
}
```

But the problem with this code is that if I've a variable product with volume instead of pack this will take the highest price of the volume and divide it by 10 and I don't want it, I want only variable product with packs.

product with pack : https://poppersplanet.com/produit/rush-original-10ml/?lang=en

product without pack : https://poppersplanet.com/produit/lubricant-gel-x-man-silicone/?lang=en

Does there is a way to remove special product for a php code or a way to use this code only for a product category.

Thx in advance for any help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're using the *ELEX WooCommerce Dynamic Pricing and Discounts Plugin* or similar, as `eha_variable_sale_price_html` is not a standard WooCommerce hook name.

In any case, you should be able to access the global `$product` object, which you can query to get its id or its product categories. Based on that, you can then build your check to determine whether you need to divide the max price by 10 or not.

For example, a criteria based on the product category would look like this (you will need to adapt the `Quantity Product` category name to your case):

```
add_filter( 'eha_variable_sale_price_html', 'pugliami_variation_price_format_min', 9999, 4 );

function pugliami_variation_price_format_min( $price, $min_price, $maxprices, $regular_price ) {
  global $product;
  $categories = get_the_terms( $product->get_id(), 'product_cat' );
  $is_quantity_product = false;
  foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
    if ( 'Quantity Product' === $category->name ) {
      $is_quantity_product = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  if ( $is_quantity_product ) {
    return sprintf( __( 'Starting from %1$s', 'woocommerce' ), wc_price( $maxprices / 10 ) );
  }
  return sprintf( __( 'Starting from %1$s', 'woocommerce' ), wc_price( $min_price ) );
}
```

Similarly, you can check if the id of the product is included in an array of ids of products whose price is based on quantity.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, i've adapted the 'Quantity Product' with the name of the category I want to divide by 10 but it also do it for every others category. No matter what category name i put it's always divide by 10. I've also added the $ in front of the last min_price.

Comment: Have you tried getting for each product all its categories? Do all the products belong to the same categories? By the way, just to be sure we are talking about the same thing, this a [WooCommerce doc](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/managing-product-taxonomies/) about product categories. Thank you for spotting the `min_price` error, I've fixed it in my answer.

Comment: I've tried main categories and sub categories. For exemple the first link with pack his in sub-category "Poppers Propyle" that is in main category "Poppers Formule" i tried both and the other product without pack that is in sub-category "Gels" in main category "Accessoires" also got the divided by 10. 

The products i want to remove from the divided by 10 are all in other categories.

I tried to target both main and sub categories but it's don't work this time 

`if ( 'Accessoires' === $category->name && 'Gels' === $category->name )`

Comment: Oh dear! I've just realised that my original answer was wrong: it was getting all the available categories, rather than only the ones the product belongs to. That's why all the products had their price divided by 10. I've fixed it now.

Comment: Thanks a lot this is working :D if i want to target sub-categories (because i'm stupid and only put my product in sub-categories) does i need to juste change $categories by $sub-categories ?

Comment: You're not stupid! Having subcategories is a valid way to configure your products. The code in my answer will return all categories and subcategories, you don't have to change anything. If you however only want to check subcategories, `$category->parent` will return the id of the parent category: it will be 0 for top level categories, and it will be a non zero number for subcategories. With that information, you can then build your criteria as complex as you need (e.g. check only the subcategories of a specific category, etc.).